# How do I get apple receipt from app store events in laravel

Tags: laravel, in-app-purchase, app-store

I am using [imdhemy/laravel-in-app-purchases](https://github.com/imdhemy/laravel-in-app-purchases) plugin to manage mobile purchases from Google and Apple. I configured Google ok and I'm handling purchase events correctly.

But with apple subscriptions (renewable subscriptions) I can verify purchases, but I can't make the events listeners to work.

This is what I have working so far:

- I can get a purchase from the mobile device and verify the receipt.
- I can store the purchase identifier in my database.
- I configured apple's push notification endpoint both for production and sandbox

My specific problem is:

- the route `/purchases/subscriptions/apple` is expecting `unified_receipt`, `unified_receipt.latest_receipt`, `unified_receipt.latest_receipt_info` and `notification_type`.
- but apple is sending `Post: "{\x22signedPayload\x22:\x22eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1N....`, if I'm not wrong, that is a JWT token, but in the library documentation, there is no information regarding JWT token.

That produces a 422 error from laravel's side, as it expects fields not sent by Apple.

Is there some extra configuration or step that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: If someone comes across this issue, the solution I found was to decrypt the JWT manually and skip all the custom events.

Answer (score 1):

If you are switch to Notification version 1 you will find all data. Version 2 send only jwt token

Answer (score 0):

If someone comes across this issue, the solution I found was to decrypt the JWT manually and skip all the custom events.